# SQL Server Reporting Services Master Page

Tags: reporting-services, birt

How can I create a master page in SSRS? Do u have any idea? I created paster page in BIRT but I couldnt find in SSRS

Answer (score 2):

Closest I think you could get, is defining a report and using it as a sub-report inside each report's header. You could then have common values (execution time, company images & text, etc.) on this report and just include it on all others.

What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am converting all reports from BIRT to SSRS. There are reports which have several pages. Therefore, the company logo and report title must stay in head of every page. I try to do this

Comment: @Omnipotent So create one report that has the logo & title, then on every other report add a header area and put the logo & title report in it as a subreport. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/selvar/archive/2010/12/28/report-headers-and-footers-with-microsoft-sql-server-reporting-services.aspx